# iptables match output rule for supplementary groups

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

The iptables utility allows for rules to match based on the process's uid or gid with the following:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT
```

I also want to add a rule to allow all members of a group called "netaccess" to use outbound traffic. I tried the following:

```
sudo groupadd -r netaccess # This created the group with gid 999
sudo usermod -aG netaccess <myUser>
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner netaccess -j ACCEPT
```

However, my outbound traffic is still being blocked. I have verified that the iptables rule was created above the final REJECT rule, so that isn't the issue. Rather, it appears that when using `iptables -m owner` with the `--gid-owner` option, it compares the exact gid of the process rather than checking if the gid is in the owner's list of supplementary groups (as defined in /etc/group). I found this by looking at this page (Ctrl+F for "owner"): http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html

Is there any way to use iptables to match rules to all members of a supplementary group? I'd like something like the following to work:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-member netaccess -j ACCEPT
```

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and have iptables v1.4.21.

Comment: A brief glance at [the source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/netfilter/xt_owner.c) indicates that it only checks the GID, not supplementary groups. So, [whatever you're trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912), you can't do it this way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was afraid of that. I'm setting up egress filtering using iptables and wanted the convenience of creating a group to allow any members to have unfiltered outbound connectivity. I can just create separate rules for each user, but wanted to create a single rule and add the users to groups. For now I will likely just add a rule for each user I want to allow outbound network access.

Comment: Depending on the environment, you could also require users to `newgrp netaccess` before accessing the network.

Comment: Wow, somehow I haven't come across `newgrp` before. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: Or its common abbreviation, `sg` (which is analogous to `su` but for groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for supplementary groups was added in [ea6cc2fd](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ea6cc2fd8a2b89ab6dcd096ba6dbc1ecbdf26564) in 2019:

```
netfilter: xt_owner: Add supplementary groups option

The XT_OWNER_SUPPL_GROUPS flag causes GIDs specified with XT_OWNER_GID
to be also checked in the supplementary groups of a process.

f_cred->group_info cannot be modified during its lifetime and f_cred
holds a reference to it so it's safe to use.

Signed-off-by: Lukasz Pawelczyk 
Signed-off-by: Pablo Neira Ayuso
```

The corresponding iptables feature is documented in [`iptables-extensions(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html):

```
--suppl-groups
       Causes group(s) specified with --gid-owner to be also checked in
       the supplementary groups of a process.
```

To do what you want, you would use this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner netaccess --suppl-groups -j ACCEPT
```